# PolarPlot with Dashed and PlotRange freezes for simple function

Tags: bugs, plotting

When I plot

```
PolarPlot[1/(1+Cos[6-t]), {t,0,2\[Pi]}, PlotRange->{{-4,4},{-4,4}}, PlotStyle->Dashed]
```

everything works normally, but when I change the numerator to 2,

```
PolarPlot[2/(1+Cos[6-t]), {t,0,2\[Pi]}, PlotRange->{{-4,4},{-4,4}}, PlotStyle->Dashed]
```

this causes Mathematica to freeze and have to kill the process. Any idea what is going on?

I'm using 10.0.0 on Linux, but I had the same issue with 10.0.0 OSX.

If I take away the PlotStyle, it works. If I take away PlotRange, it works. If I change Cos[6-t] to Cos[t], it works.

Comment: Good question. Actually this happens with the first plot as well for me, with *Mathematica* 10.0.0 and OS X. Changing `Cos[6-t]` to `Cos[t]` does not resolve it for me either.

Comment: on V10.1 windows 7, I get no crash and empty plot? ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/fSueo.png) ps. for problem like this it is best to give version number and platform.

Comment: It gives two nice blank plots on V9

Comment: ^edited to add version number(s) -- 10.0.0 on Linux (but I see the same behavior with 10.0.0 on OSX)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Too long for a comment and maybe just an observation.

I'm on 10.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (September 10, 2014) and have also a kind of freeze, the rainbow shell comes up and rotates for 10-15 seconds. This effect again fetches 3-5 times. Very uncomfortable ...

But if I set `PlotRange -> 4` and `Performance Goal -> "Speed"` I have not freeze at all.

```
PolarPlot[1/(1 + Cos[6 - t]), {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, PlotRange -> 4, 
 PlotStyle -> Dashed, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"]
```

[image]

```
PolarPlot[2/(1 + Cos[6 - t]), {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, PlotRange -> 4, 
 PlotStyle -> Dashed, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Lou, the PerformanceGoal option causes it not to freeze up.

Comment: @Jacob Schwartz, My pleasure!

Comment: (+1) This workaround works for MMa 10.0.1 under Win7 x64.

Answer (score 2):

the plot is empty when the upper limit of t is `2 Pi`. I am not sure why. also I got problem when the `PlotStyle->Dashed`. Not sure why.

This gives the plot.

```
PolarPlot[2/(1 + Cos[6 - t]), {t, 0, 2 \[Pi] - .1}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 PlotRange -> {{-40, 40}, {-10, 10}}, PlotStyle -> Red]
```

[image]

Comment: A funny thing. If I try to repeat the above solution, if works. It still works with the option `PlotRange -> {{-4, 10}, {-5, 5}} `. And with such an option one can make sure that the maximum value of x is about one. Therefore, I expect that the option `PlotRange -> {{-4, 2}, {-5, 5}} ` will simply give a more detailed view. Instead I see an empty plot. It is Mma 10.0, Win7. Looks very much like a bug for me.